# I assume that a parameter is real and positive, but Mathematica still assigns a phase to it

Tags: assumptions

If I run this line of code

`Assuming[{Element[a, Reals], a > 0}, TrigToExp[ComplexExpand[Sqrt[a]]]]`

I get

```
(a^2)^(1/4) E^(1/2 I Arg[a]).
```

Why does Mathematica assume that the parameter `a` has a phase, after I declared that it is real and positive?

Comment: Most *Mathematica* functions ignore assumptions. `TrigToExp` appears to be one of those.

Comment: Could use `Refine`, as that accounts for assumptions.

Comment: `Simplify[TrigToExp[ComplexExpand[Sqrt[a]]], 
 Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Reals, a > 0}]` yields the expected result

Comment: Only functions whose `Options` include `Assumptions` make use of `$Assumptions` or the assumptions specified in `Assuming`. Neither `TrigToExp` nor `ComplexExpand` take the option `Assumptions`.